# Antlr beginner mismatchedtoken question

Tags: antlr

I'm just starting out with Antlr, so please forgive the noob question here.  I'm lost.  Any help is appreciated.

This is my grammar script:

```
grammar test;

script : 
    'begin script' IDENT ':'

    'end script' IDENT
    ;

IDENT : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*
    ;
```

This is the script I'm trying to run it against:

```
begin script spork:

end script spork
```

The result in ANTLRWorks 1.3.1:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually want to tell ANTLR to ignore whitespace with a lexer rule:

```
WHITESPACE
    :   ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+
        { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

Comment: +1 - you said what I said except you actually know what you're doing

Comment: @Nate C-K - perhaps... or maybe I just got lucky ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with AntLR, but my guess is that the lexer is producing a token for the newline and it's not matched in your grammar.

Normally when you're writing a parser you have to tell the lexer explicitly to ignore whitespace and line endings. But I could be wrong, that could be something that AntLR is supposed to do for you.